# numpy finite difference for Laplace PDE with polygonal boundaries

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-analysis

The numpy script at **http://www.physics.drexel.edu/courses/Comp_Phys/Physics-306/demo6.1.py** demonstrates how to solve the Laplace PDE for a **RECTANGULAR** domain.

Question: is there a similar URL for **POLYGONIAL** boundary conditions? (preferably with python/numpy, but similar languages would be OK too).

Answer (score 0):

I coded a solution based on the code you provided.

I took the parametric polygon equation to make a geometric transform, and it works, because we find similary result when there is 4 edges. For the boundaries conditions I used the sinus function, the opposite or the null function to initialize an edge.

https://github.com/fr4nky89/PolygonLaplacePDE/blob/master/python.py